# Why is the error of my AdaBoost implementation not going down?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, adaboost

I'm trying to implement Adaboost M1 in Python from this pseudocode:
[image]

I have gotten some way, however, my the amount of "wrong predictions" is not declining.

I have checked my weight-updating function, and it seems to be updating the weights correctly.

The error might be in the classifier, since the number of "incorrect predictions" is the same integer every other iteration- I have tried 100 iterations. I have no idea why it is not giving less incorrect per iteration.

A tip would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks:)

```
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

df = pd.read_csv("./dataset(3)/adaboost_train.csv")
X_train = df.loc[:,'x1':'x10']
Y_train = df[['y']]



def adaBoost(X_train,Y_train):
    classifiers = []
    # initializing the weights:
    N = len(Y_train)
    w_i = [1 / N] * N

    T = 20
    x_train = (X_train.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1))
    clf_errors = []

    for t in range(T):
        print("Iteration:", t)
        # clf = clf2.fit(X_train,Y_train, sample_weight = w_i)

        clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)
        clf.fit(X_train, Y_train, sample_weight = w_i)

        #Predict all the values:
        y_pred = []
        for sample in x_train:
            p = clf.predict([sample])
            p = p[0]
            y_pred.append(p)
        num_of_incorrect = calculate_error_clf(y_pred, Y_train)


        clf_errors.append(num_of_incorrect)

        error_internal = calc_error(w_i,Y_train,y_pred)

        alpha = np.log((1-error_internal)/ error_internal)
        print(alpha)

        # Add the predictions, error and alpha for later use for every iteration
        classifiers.append((y_pred, error_internal, alpha))

        if t == 2 and y_pred == classifiers[0][0]:
            print("TRUE")


        w_i = update_weights(w_i,y_pred,Y_train,alpha,clf)


def calc_error(weights,Y_train,y_pred):
    err = 0
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        if y_pred[i] != Y_train['y'].iloc[i]:
            err= err + weights[i]
    # Normalizing the error:
    err = err/np.sum(weights)
    return err

# If the prediction is true, return 0. If it is not true, return 1.
def check_pred(y_p, y_t):
    if y_p == y_t:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def update_weights(w,y_pred,Y_train,alpha,clf):
    for j in range(len(w)):
        if y_pred[j] != Y_train['y'].iloc[j]:
            w[j] = w[j]* (np.exp( alpha * 1))
    return w

def calculate_error_clf(y_pred, y):
    sum_error = 0
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if y_pred[i] != y.iloc[i]['y']:
            sum_error += 1
        e = (y_pred[i] - y.iloc[i]['y'])**2


        #sum_error += e
    sum_error = sum_error
    return sum_error
```

I am expecting the error to go down, but it is not. For example:

```
iteration 1: num_of_incorrect 4444
iteration 2: num_of_incorrect 4762
iteration 3: num_of_incorrect 4353
iteration 4: num_of_incorrect 4762
iteration 5: num_of_incorrect 4450
iteration 6: num_of_incorrect 4762
...
does not converge
```

Answer (score 3):

The number of misclassifications will NOT go down with each iteration (since each classifier is a week classifier). It is an ensemble model where it gives more weight to the previously misclassified sample. So in the next iteration some of the the previously misclassified sampled will be correctly classified but this might also result in previously correctly classified samples going wrong (hence iteration level error is not improving).  Even though each classifier is weak, since the final output is the weighted sum of all the classifiers the final classification converge to a strong learner (see line 3 of the algorithm).

#### My Implementation using numpy

```
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer, classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

data = load_breast_cancer()
X_train = data.data
Y_train = np.where(data.target == 0, 1, -1)

def adaBoost(X_train,Y_train):
    classifiers = []
    # initializing the weights:
    N = len(Y_train)
    w_i = np.array([1 / N] * N)

    T = 20
    clf_errors = []

    for t in range(T):
        clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)
        clf.fit(X_train, Y_train, sample_weight = w_i)

        #Predict all the values:
        y_pred = clf.predict(X_train)   
        #print (confusion_matrix(Y_train, y_pred))

        # Line 2(b) of algorithm 
        error = np.sum(np.where(Y_train != y_pred, w_i, 0))/np.sum(w_i)
        print("Iteration: {0}, Missed: {1}".format(t, np.sum(np.where(Y_train != y_pred, 1, 0))))

        # Line 2(c) of algorithm 
        alpha = np.log((1-error)/ error)
        classifiers.append((alpha, clf))
        # Line 2(d) of algorithm 
        w_i = np.where(Y_train != y_pred, w_i*np.exp(alpha), w_i)
    return classifiers

clfs = adaBoost(X_train, Y_train)

# Line 3 of algorithm 
def predict(clfs, x):
    s = np.zeros(len(x))
    for (alpha, clf) in clfs:
        s += alpha*clf.predict(x)
    return np.sign(s)

print (confusion_matrix(Y_train, predict(clfs,X_train)))
```

**Output**:

`Iteration: 0, Missed: 44
Iteration: 1, Missed: 48
Iteration: 2, Missed: 182
Iteration: 3, Missed: 73
Iteration: 4, Missed: 102
Iteration: 5, Missed: 160
Iteration: 6, Missed: 185
Iteration: 7, Missed: 69
Iteration: 8, Missed: 357
Iteration: 9, Missed: 127
Iteration: 10, Missed: 256
Iteration: 11, Missed: 160
Iteration: 12, Missed: 298
Iteration: 13, Missed: 64
Iteration: 14, Missed: 221
Iteration: 15, Missed: 113
Iteration: 16, Missed: 261
Iteration: 17, Missed: 368
Iteration: 18, Missed: 49
Iteration: 19, Missed: 171
[[354   3]
 [  3 209]]`

`precision   recall  f1-score   support
-1          0.99        0.99      0.99       357
1           0.99        0.99      0.99       212
avg / total 0.99        0.99      0.99       569`

As you can see, the no:of misses will not improve, however if you check the confusion matrix (uncomment in the code) you will see that some of the previously misclassified samples will be correctly classified. Finally, for predictions since we weight the classifiers by the error, the weight sum converges to a strong classifier (as seen in the final predictions made).

Comment: Here, you've both printed the number of misclassified labels, for each iteration. What about err_m? Would we expect that one to go down or to increase?